# How to save Information in Database using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mysql-python

I'm getting different information for a particular thing and i'm storing those information in a dictionary

e.g.  `{property1:val , property2:val, property3:val}`

now I have several dictionary of this type (as I get many things ..each dictionary is for a thing)

now I want to save information in DB so there would be as many columns as key:value pair in a dictionary

so what is the best or simplest way to do that.

Please provide all steps to do that (I mean syntax for login in DB, push data into row or execute sql query etc... I hope there wont be more than 4 or 5 steps )

PS: All dictionaries have the same keys, and each key always has the same value-type . and also number of columns are predefined.

Comment: Please, don't ask others to do your work. "Provide all steps for everything" is an offense when there are so many tutorials in each database and language bindings for each database websites.

Answer (score 2):

For MYSQL you will have to know beforehand how many columns you will need.
Stop using MySQL. Use some NoSQL database. It's usually simpler.

Try [MongoDB](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) or [CouchDB](http://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/).

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionaries all have the same keys, and each key always has the same value-type, it would be pretty straight-forward to map this to a relational database like MySQL.

Alternatively, you could convert your dictionaries to objects and use an ORM like SQLAlchemy to do the back-end work.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong!

Make an object that represents a row in the database, use `__getitem__` to pretend it's a dictionary.

Put your database logic in that.

Don't go all noSQL unless your tables are not related. Just by being tables they are ideal for SQL!

Answer (score 0):

[Pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted) is a nice little module providing a wide range of DB possibilities.  I am not sure on your exact needs so it may be in fact overkill for your current situation but has provided me with a useful way to connect to a SQL Express database.

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("Alter table Dict add property1 [datatype])
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
```

You could create the table if it doesn't exist already and then for each dict pair alter the table and add that column and insert the values as needed.